# Tasks are running sequentially for some reason

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Case 1: I have a console test app and libraries.  The test app calls async methods on classes in those libraries that are meant to run in parallel.  Example Code

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var myTask = RetrieveRecordSet<TestClass3>();
        }
```

This works as expected in the console app, meaning all 100 Tasks are queued at the same time and the Tasks perform in parallel in the background, proven by their Console output.

Case 2: Same code, just in a WPF app instead of a console app.  Now for some reason, the Tasks run sequentially.

Case 3: I also tried the following modification to the WPF app to no avail:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RetrieveRecordSet<TestClass3>());
        }
```

Case 4: I then tried the following but it blocks the UI and is still sequential

```
        Parallel.For(0, 100, a => RetrieveRecordSet<TestClass3>());
```

Is there a way to get the same non-blocking parallel behavior that I get from Case 1 in a WPF app?

Comment: How does `RetrieveRecordSet` work? Show how it starts the task and what the task looks like. Does a running task hog a thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers folks.  In the end, the answer is much more nefarious, and I'm still not sure what the problem is but I found a workaround.  The underlying code is making WCF service calls.  Using Task Parallel library to make a bunch of parallel WCF calls the first time a channel is used, will serialize those calls.  I serendipitously discovered that if you 'prime' the channel with a single call first, await the response, and THEN slam it with a bunch of parallel WCF calls, you then get full parallelism.  Is there a less hacky perhaps proper way to prime a WCF channel as such?  Is this a bug in WCF or TPL?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Await Task.Run(() => 
{
    Parallel.For(0,100, ()=> RetrieveRecordSet<>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parallel.For is indeed a blocking operation. If you want the Parallel.For loop to run on a separate thread than the UI:

```
new Thread(() => Parallel.For(0, 100, index => RetrieveRecordSet<TestClass3>())).Start();
```

Or

```
new Task(() => Parallel.For(0, 100, index => RetrieveRecordSet<TestClass3>())).Start();
```